# Can I import NFT's metadata into a smart contract?

Tags: json, metadata, blockchain, ipfs, nft

When we want to mint an NFT with its own metadata, the asset file and JSON file should be uploaded to IPFS before the minting.
And we mint a new NFT by sending transactions to the smart contract and within the transaction, the token URI(hashed URI from IPFS) would be set as JSON metadata URI of the token.

Now I am wondering whether there is a way to import the attributes from JSON on IPFS into a smart contract and use the data like const variables in the contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it is going to cost you alot. You need to create a mapping in smart contract.

```
 mapping(string ->Metadata) private tokenURIToMetadata
```

Since it is mapped from string, it cannot be public. so create a function

```
  function getMetadata(string tokenUri) public returns(Metadata){
         return tokenURIToMetadata[tokenUri]
    }
```

also create Metadata struct:

```
struct Metadata{
  string name;
  string description;
  string image;
 }
```

And then you have to add new medata to the mapping:

```
function addMetada(string memory tokenUri,?????????){}
```

Since we cannot pass json object as an argument to the `addMetada`, now you have to create a separate mapping for each property of the metadata object. So the cost will be crazy amount.

Instead, you could write the metadata to the filesystem or database but this would not be a good option.